# Could wordpress theme css/js conflict with Wordpress visual mode posting?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

As I understand it when posting using visual mode in wordpress hitting enter inserts a line break, or wraps the previous text in paragraph tags.  Also, you have the added options of highlighting text and select header or pre or paragraph.

The problem I am having is that, in visual mode, when I hit enter or when I select a block of text and select paragraph no tags are being inserted at all.

Example.

```
<pre>sample text</pre>
<h1>sample text</h1>
sample text
sample text
```

The results of the above are obvious, I get two correctly formatted 'sample texts' and then I see the two lines of text that are supposed to be paragraphs as 'sample textsample text'.  Nothing I have done short of manually adding the tags in the text (html) editor has fixed this.

I am working from a theme that I have built myself so I was wondering if anything I did in the theme could interfere with that.

Additional note: in the content-page.php I am using the_content(); not the_excerpt(); so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I found this php function in the underscores base theme that I had built from was stripping the paragraph tags.

```
remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

I removed that from functions.php and the formatting returned to normal.